# python polars : apply function efficiently on parts of dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to optimize `apply` on polars the way I did on pandas (which might entirely be the wrong way to proceed...).

I have a function I'm not managing but that I have to apply to parts of my dataframe; to assert reproducibility, let's say this is `lat_lon_parse` from the `lat_lon_parser` package.

```
from lat_lon_parser import parse as lat_lon_parse

def test_lat_lon_parse(x):
    try:
        print(f"parsing {x}")
        return lat_lon_parse(x)
    except Exception:
        return None
```

Let's also say that your dataframe, reflecting true data, contains mixed data.

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'A':["1", "2", "5°N", "4°S"], "B":[1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

For efficiency's sake, I don't want to apply `test_lat_lon_parse` on rows 1 and 2 (as I could do a simple `.cast()` operation and get the same result). What is the state-of-the-art way to proceed ?

In pandas, I would have computed an index and applied my function on the subset of the dataframe only.

In polars, I see two ways of proceeding :

```
mask = pl.col('A').str.contains('°')

# way #1
def way_1(df):
  return df.with_columns(
    pl.when(mask)
    .then(pl.col('A').apply(test_lat_lon_parse))
    .otherwise(pl.col('A'))
    .cast(pl.Float64)
    )

# way #2
def way_2(df):
  return pl.concat([
    df.filter(mask).with_columns(pl.col('A').apply(test_lat_lon_parse).alias('dummy')),
    df.filter(~mask).with_columns(pl.col('A').cast(pl.Float64).alias('dummy'))
    ])
```

You will see that way #1 will apply the function on each row (hence the `print`s); note that this is not as trivial as it seems as your applied function may also trigger exceptions when encountering strange data. For instance, you can't cast to `pl.Float64` inside the `otherwise` part of the expression because it will be applied to the whole series - and fail.

The way #2 will execute the function on the only subset I specified but will alter the dataframe's order.

I used `timeit`s to compare the two processes. I got those results:

```
# way #1: 
%timeit way_1(df)
>> 443 µs ± 76.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# way #2:
%timeit way_2(df)
>> 1.49 ms ± 462 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

When I increase the dataframe's size, it shows (not unsurprisingly) that way #1 does not handle scalibility best:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'A':["1", "2", "5°N", "4°S"]*10000, "B":[1, 2, 3, 4]*10000})

# way #1: 
%timeit way_1(df)
>> 400 ms ± 48.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# way #2:
>> 234 ms ± 59.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is my understanding of polars' proceeding right? Are there better ways to handle this (and how do they handle scalibility)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [apply docs:](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.apply.html)

> **Warning:** If `return_dtype` is not provided, this may lead to unexpected results. We allow this, but it is considered a bug in the user’s query.

We will specify `return_dtype=pl.Float64` for the examples.

---

You can use `.when().then().apply` to apply only the masked values.

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(mask).then(pl.col('A'))
     .apply(test_lat_lon_parse, return_dtype=pl.Float64)
)
```

```
parsing 5°N
parsing 4°S
shape: (4, 1)
┌──────┐
│ A    │
│ ---  │
│ f64  │
╞══════╡
│ null │
│ null │
│ 5.0  │
│ -4.0 │
└──────┘
```

You want the values when the cast succeeds, otherwise you want the values from the apply on the mask:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col('A').cast(pl.Float64, strict=False).is_not_null())
     .then(pl.col('A').cast(pl.Float64, strict=False))
     .otherwise(
        pl.when(mask).then(pl.col('A'))
         .apply(test_lat_lon_parse, return_dtype=pl.Float64)
     )
)
```

```
parsing 5°N
parsing 4°S
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ B   │
│ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f64  ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═════╡
│ 1.0  ┆ 1   │
│ 2.0  ┆ 2   │
│ 5.0  ┆ 3   │
│ -4.0 ┆ 4   │
└──────┴─────┘
```

To choose conditionally between null and non-null is also a [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce) operation:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.coalesce(
      pl.col('A').cast(pl.Float64, strict=False),
      pl.when(mask).then(pl.col('A')).apply(test_lat_lon_parse, return_dtype=pl.Float64)
   )
)
```

Or you can explicitly `.fill_null`:

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.col('A').cast(pl.Float64, strict=False).fill_null(
      pl.when(mask).then(pl.col('A'))
        .apply(test_lat_lon_parse, return_dtype=pl.Float64)
   )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is clear and I didn't think to use the `fill_null` instead of `otherwise` which allows you to deport the `apply` ; regarding the performance, it seems to be equivalent to way#2. I still don't get it how way#1 can (sometimes) be faster than your code on small dataframes though...

Comment: Can you explain how you end up with floats by the way ? Is `fill_null` triggering any cast behind the hood? (`pl.col("A")` had a Utf8 dtype at before...)

Comment: The `.apply()` is returning a `f64` Series. However, the `.fill_null` should cast it back to `str` as that is what happens elsewhere in polars: `pl.Series([1.0, None]).fill_null('2')`

Comment: I've updated the answer with strict casting and hopefully a better explanation. I've removed the original approach as it's not clear if that behaviour is a "bug" or not.

Comment: from the apply docs: *"If return_dtype is not provided, this may lead to unexpected results. We allow this, but it is considered a bug in the user’s query."* - setting `return_dtype` to float with the original approach results in a `str` column. i.e. the "correct" casting one would expect.